# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like help about this error: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.".

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Capitulo 2 - Desafio 3</title>
</head>

<body>

    <ul></ul>

    <script>

        var nomes = ["Paulo", "Jonas", "Samuel"];
        var listElement = document.querySelector('ul');

        for (nome of nomes) {
            var liElement = document.createElement('li');
            var textElement = document.createTextNode(nome);

        liElement.appendChild(textElement);
        textElement.appendChild(liElement);

        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Text nodes can't have children... surely that's a copy paste failure or a typo and you meant it to be `listElement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is here `textElement.appendChild(liElement);` , it has to be `listElement.appendChild(liElement)`

```js
var nomes = ["Paulo", "Jonas", "Samuel"];
var listElement = document.querySelector('ul');

for (nome of nomes) {
  var liElement = document.createElement('li');
  var textElement = document.createTextNode(nome);

  liElement.appendChild(textElement);
  listElement.appendChild(liElement);

}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```